# open multi wire electrical branch circuits

Tags: wiring

I have 2 multi branch circuits in a 50's house. I put in a new line & breaker to replace an old line that was shorted out. When I went to remove the old wires, the whole multi circuit went dead. I checked to see how the wires ran in the main box and found the red wire was on the left side and the black wire was on the right side, also the main tied breakers do not shut off the right side circuit breakers you have to shut them off individually to shut off current. How do I get the currant back to the original multi circuit?

Comment: If your main is not working correctly have you verified the panel is providing the proper voltage? The black and red wires do not matter top or bottom left or right they just need to be on a double breaker or 2 with handle ties, + your grounds and neutral need to be on the proper buss unless this is a true main then they can be on the same buss but not under the same screw or clamp. What is your voltage from breaker to breaker? Then what is the voltage from each breaker to neutral?

Comment: Can you post a photo of your panel please?